# How to send string in get path (Node.js)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, get

User can enter different characters for `search`. For this reason, errors appear when the user enters characters e.g. / or %. How to send the variable `search` in a get query?

```
router.get('/get/:search', (req, res) => {
    Label.aggregate(pipeline)
        .then(result => {
            res.json(result);
        })
        .catch(err => {
            res.status(500).send(err);
        });
});
```

in frontend:

```
api.get(`${'get'}/${search}`);
```

Comment: [encodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent)

Comment: `api.get(\`get/${encodeURIComponent(search)}\`);`

Comment: Thanks @Chris G and ASDFGerte it works :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used solution from @Chris G and @ASDFGerte in comment
`` api.get(`get/${encodeURIComponent(search)}`); ``

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent

Answer (score 1):

for it javascript have standard functions  encodeURIComponent(param), decodeURIComponent(encodedParam)

on front-end
user insert

```
 const word = 'sear%ch?';
```

before append word to api url, need encode it.

```
const encodedWord = encodeURIComponent(word);
```

on backend after obtain searchWord from url need decode it.

```
 const word = decodeURIComponent(encodedWord);
```